# How to set timeout for thread in case of no response and terminate the thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

Let's say we have a code sample as below which prints `hello, world` after 5 seconds. I want a way to check if `Timer` thread took more than 5 seconds then terminate the thread.

```
from threading import Timer
from time import sleep


def hello():
    sleep(50)
    print "hello, world"

t = Timer(5, hello)
# after 5 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed
t.start()
```

In the above code block `hello` will take more than 5 seconds to process.

consider `hello` function, a call to outside server that returns no response and even no exception for timeout or anything! I wanted to simulate the issue with `sleep` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `signal` and call its `alarm` method. An exception (which you can handle) will be raised after the timeout time has passed. See an (incomplete) example below.

```
import signal

class TimeoutException (Exception):
    pass

def signalHandler (signum, frame):
    raise TimeoutException ()

timeout_duration = 5

signal.signal (signal.SIGALRM, signalHandler)
signal.alarm (timeout_duration)

try:
    """Do something that has a possibility of taking a lot of time 
    and exceed the timeout_duration"""
except TimeoutException as exc:
    "Notify your program that the timeout_duration has passed"
finally:
    #Clean out the alarm
    signal.alarm (0)
```

You can read more about Python's `signal` here https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html.

Comment: Thank you it works like a charm. Just a side note: `time_duration` cannot be float.

Comment: Thank you. I have now changed it to `timeout_duration = 5`. I am very glad it helps.

Comment: I am not quite sure but this seems to be only working on Linux since the signal handler has SIGALARM. When running on Windows I get the error "AttributeError": 'module' object has no attribute 'SIGALARM'